# Send file to remote php from local python in $_FILES

Tags: php, python, file

Preface: I started learning Python one month ago, please don't yell at me :)
I have a full developed site written in PHP, with all the functions I need with pages to insert "stuff" in the database. I am developing a command line program to insert the same thing and send them to the PHP scripts in the $_POST array, but I have no idea on how to send the file so that it would come up in the $_FILES array.

Here is what I have so far:

I send the $_POST values using the urllib modules and it works just fine

```
import urllib.request
import urllib.parse
data=urllib.parse.urlencode({"hello":"Yo!", "some":"AlphaBetaParkingLot"})
data=data.encode('utf_8')
request=urllib.request.Request("http://www.site.it/read_from_py.php")
f=urllib.request.urlopen(request, data)
out=f.read().decode('utf-8')
if out[0]=="1":
    print("Connection acquired!")
else:
    print("No connection!")
    print("Exit!")
    #Then actually exit!
```

...I read the filename from the local computer by prompting a choose file dialogbox...

```
from tkinter import Tk
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
Tk().withdraw()
filename=askopenfilename()
```

...but then I have no idea on what to do with the filename. I have looked around and I have seen no way on how to send this to the $_FILES in PHP.

I have a "dirty" solution: creating a temporary html with a form just with the file and make it choose from there, but I was wondering if there was a cleaner solution.

Thanks!

P.S. If you are wondering if I have all the things I need in the PHP scripts, why would I need this Python program? Well, you would be correct, I wouldn't need it but it's not up to me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Like This

```
import urllib,MultipartPostHandler,urllib2,cookielib
cookies = cookielib.CookieJar()
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cookies),MultipartPostHandler.MultipartPostHandler)
urllib2.install_opener(opener)
login = urllib.urlencode(dict(admin_user='admin',admin_pass='****'))
o=opener.open('http://some_domain_name.com/admin/index.php',login)
print o.read()
raw_params={"adtitle":"sample title",
        "area":"sample area",
        "addesc":"<p>sample post</p>",
    "pic[0]":open("indian_eye.jpg", "rb"), #File Goes Here
    "pic[1]":open("nature.jpg", "rb"),
        "subcatid":"1",
    "do":"post",
        }
url="http://YOUR.php?cityid=15&subcatid=1"
opener.open(url, raw_params)
```

Hope it works!

Comment: Yay! I think it worked! Thank you!! Now I have to convert it for Python3 (or the other way around)